# How to get the Local Host Ip address on iPhone in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to get the Local Host Ip address on `iPhone` in `swift` ?

I have reference the [How to get Ip address in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626117/how-to-get-ip-address-in-swift) , It needs to `#include <ifaddrs.h>` and the link mention the `getifaddrs()` is defined in `<ifaddrs.h>`, which is not included by default. Therefore you have to create a bridging header and add `#include <ifaddrs.h>`

What is the create the `bridging header` mean here ?
How to create the `bridging header`?

Is it mean , copy the `ifaddrs.h` file to my `swift` project ?

or does there has other way to get the `Local Host Ip address` on `iPhone` in `swift`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't have a code for swift but do have a code for objective - c, i can suggest if you couldn't find a code for swift then make a class with Objective - c class and write a method that would return NSString of your local Host ip.

Comment: if you like my suggestion then i would give you code in answer.

Comment: @SyedAliSalman OK , I approve your suggestion !

Comment: allright, let me wirte code.

Comment: So your question is not "how to get the local IP address", but "how to create a bridging header file". So your title is misleading.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry , that is also my question. I have modify the content.

Comment: "How to get the local IP address in Swift" is (hopefully) answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626117/how-to-get-ip-address-in-swift that you referenced, and that code should still work. So your *only problem* is how to create a bridging header file where you can add the required `#include <ifaddrs.h>`. And that is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift/24005242#24005242. The easiest way is to add *any* Objective-C file to your project. Then Xcode will automatically ask if you want a bridging header.

Answer (score 0):

To import a set of Objective-C files in the same app target as your Swift code, you rely on an Objective-C bridging header to expose those files to Swift.

> Xcode offers to create this header file when you add a Swift file to
>   an existing Objective-C app, or an Objective-C file to an existing
>   Swift app.
>
> Alternatively, you can create a bridging header yourself by choosing
>   File > New > File > (iOS or OS X) > Source > Header File.
>
> You’ll need to edit the bridging header file to expose your
>   Objective-C code to your Swift code
>
> To import Objective-C code into Swift from the same target
>
> 1. In your Objective-C bridging header file, import every Objective-C
>      header you want to expose to Swift.
> 2. Under Build Settings, make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header
>      build setting under Swift Compiler - Code Generation has a path to
>      the header.

You can find more info on bridging-header [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)