# How can I output this function to be a simple string?

Tags: swift

I am trying to get access to the private IP in my app and I have the following code which gets the local IP and returns it. The issue is that it is returning a [String] not String and every time I try and use it I get an error. Here is the code (from [How to get Ip address in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626117/how-to-get-ip-address-in-swift/25627545#25627545)):

```
func getIFAddresses() -> [String] {
    var addresses = [String]()

    // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs> = nil
    if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {

        // For each interface ...
        for (var ptr = ifaddr; ptr != nil; ptr = ptr.memory.ifa_next) {
            let flags = Int32(ptr.memory.ifa_flags)
            var addr = ptr.memory.ifa_addr.memory

            // Check for running IPv4, IPv6 interfaces. Skip the loopback interface.
            if (flags & (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_LOOPBACK)) == (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING) {
                if addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET) || addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

                    // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                    var hostname = [CChar](count: Int(NI_MAXHOST), repeatedValue: 0)
                    if (getnameinfo(&addr, socklen_t(addr.sa_len), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                        nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0) {
                            if let address = String.fromCString(hostname) {
                                addresses.append(address)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
    }
    print(addresses)


    return addresses
}
```

and here is how I am trying to use it:

```
self.privateIp.title = getIFAddresses()
```

However when I do this, I get an error:

> Cannot assign a value of type "[String]" to a value of type "String".

If I try and cast it like this:

```
self.privateIp.title = getIFAddresses() as! String
```

I get the following error:

> Cast from '[String]' to unrelated type 'String' always fails.

Comment: [String] is array of strings you are trying to assign the array value to string, first assign the value from getIFAddresses() to an array like let arr = getIFAddresses() and try to access the first object from that array self.privateIp.title = arr.first

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[String]` is an array of string so it can contain more than one item.
If you want first element from the array you can use:

```
if let ipAdd = getIFAddresses().first {
    self.privateIp.title = ipAdd
}
```

It's equivalent to `getIFAddresses()[0]` but more safety because if the array is empty call to `getIFAddresses()[0]` will crash your app.

You can call `last` to get the last one or you can enumerate all of the items inside the array.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this as best answer in 5 minutes :D