# Thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter not found in Swift using getifaddrs()

Tags: swift, networking, network-interface

I have the following code to get a list of all adapters on my MacBook:

```
if getifaddrs(&addresses) == 0
        {
            let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: addresses, count: 16)
            for address in buffer
            {
                let rawData = address.ifa_data
                let name = address.ifa_name
                let socket: sockaddr = address.ifa_addr.pointee

                if rawData != nil && name != nil && socket.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK)
                {
                    let adapterName = String(utf8String: UnsafePointer<CChar>(name!))
                    let adapter = Adapter(name: adapterName!)
                    adapters.append(adapter)
                }
            }
        }
```

The code works great and (almost) all adapters are returned. If a Thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter is used, this network is not returned.

How can I get this adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes that `getifaddrs()` returns an *array* of `struct ifaddrs`, and that is not true. The function stores a reference to a
*linked list* at the given address, with the `ifa_next` member pointing
to the next element (or `nil` for the last element).

Here is an example how to traverse the list and store the interface
names into an array (a modification of the code in [How to get Ip address in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626117/how-to-get-ip-address-in-swift/25627545#25627545)):

```
func getInterfaceNames() -> [String] {

    var names = [String]()

    // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
    guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return [] }
    guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return [] }

    // For each interface ...
    for ptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
        let addr = ptr.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee
        if addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) {
            let name = String(cString: ptr.pointee.ifa_name)
            names.append(name)
        }
    }

    return names
}
```

On my iMac, this gives

```
["lo0", "gif0", "stf0", "en1", "en2", "en3", "p2p0", "awdl0", "en0", "bridge0", "utun0"]
```

including "bridge0" for the Thunderbolt bridge, whereas your code
only returns

```
"lo0", "gif0", "stf0", "en1"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.