# Swift getnameinfo unreliable results for IPv6

Tags: swift, sockaddr, getnameinfo

I have the following extension on `sockaddr`:

```
extension sockaddr {
  /// Indicates if this is an IPv4 address.
  var isIPv4: Bool {
    return sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET)
  }

  /// Indicates if this is an IPv6 address.
  var isIPv6: Bool {
    return sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET6)
  }

  /// Returns the address in string notation.
  var address: String? {
    var result: String = ""
    var me = self
    var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))

    if getnameinfo(&me, socklen_t(me.sa_len), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {
       result = String(cString: hostname)
    }

    return result
  }
}
```

In an other part of my code I'm calling `getifaddrs` to get the interface addresses of the current device. The code above works fine for IPv4, but is somewhat unreliable for IPv6.

I get results like: `192.168.1.10` and `fe80::e0fa:1204:100:0`

When I change the line `var result: String = ""` to `var result: String? = nil`. The IPv6 addresses suddenly become `fe80::`, the rest is cut off.

Even weirder, when I just switch the `var result` and the `var me = self` lines like this:

```
extension sockaddr {
  /// Indicates if this is an IPv4 address.
  var isIPv4: Bool {
    return sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET)
  }

  /// Indicates if this is an IPv6 address.
  var isIPv6: Bool {
    return sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET6)
  }

  /// Returns the address in string notation.
  var address: String? {
    var me = self
    var result: String = ""
    var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))

    if getnameinfo(&me, socklen_t(me.sa_len), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0 {
       result = String(cString: hostname)
    }

    return result
  }
}
```

Then the function will only work for IPv4 addresses. The `getnameinfo` will return 4 (FAIL).

This is during debugging, with no optimizations that I know of. It doesn't matter if I run it on a simulator or real device.

Could someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: As I said in response to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426911/xcode-address-sanitizer-issue-with-sockaddr: A `struct sockaddr` *cannot* hold an IPv6 address. So if you get correct results then by pure chance. – How do you use that extension method with `getifaddrs()`? Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25627545/1187415, which (now) works correctly?

Comment: Yes I did have a look. The line `let addr = ptr.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee` results in a `sockaddr`. If you check the definition, you'll see the following: `public var ifa_addr: UnsafeMutablePointer<sockaddr>!`. Basically all I did is move the part that comes after that to an extension on `sockaddr`.

Comment: Also the definition of `getnameinfo` starts with `public func getnameinfo(_: UnsafePointer<sockaddr>!,`. And `getnameinfo` can resolve both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Comment: `getnameinfo()` takes a *pointer* to a `sockaddr`, not the `sockaddr` itself. `ptr.pointee.ifa_addr` is the pointer obtained from `getifaddrs()` and can point to an IPv4 or to an IPv6 address. – You are right: `let addr = ptr.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee` copies only the "common" part, that is for convenience and only used to access `addr.sa_family`. But the *pointer* is passed to `getnameinfo()` (Actually I had that wrong originally, if you look at the last edit of the answer)

Comment: Ok, but what is the difference between doing it that way and doing it via an extension? I'm passing `&me` to `getnameinfo` which is a pointer to a `sockaddr` right?

Comment: As soon as you copy `let addr = ptr.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee`, a part of the IPv6 address is lost, only the "common" part (`sockaddr`)  is copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `getnameinfo` expects a pointer that can either be a `sockaddr_in` or a `sockaddr_in6`. The definition of the function is a bit confusing because it expects a `sockaddr` pointer.

Because I'm using an extension to extract the IP address a copy is being made of the memory contents. This isn't a problem for IPv4 because the size of a `sockaddr_in` is the same size as a `sockaddr`. However for IPv6, the `sockaddr_in6` is larger than the `sockaddr` struct and some relevant information is cut off.

The order of my commands probably determined what was stored in memory at the location directly after the `sockaddr` address. Sometimes it would look like a proper IPv6 address, but in reality incorrect.

I've resolved this issue by moving my extension to the network interface `ifaddrs`:

```
extension ifaddrs {
  /// Returns the IP address.
  var ipAddress: String? {
    var buffer = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
    let address = ifa_addr.pointee
    let result = getnameinfo(ifa_addr, socklen_t(address.sa_len), &buffer, socklen_t(buffer.count), nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
    return result == 0 ? String(cString: buffer) : nil
  }
}
```

Thank you @MartinR finding the cause of the problem!