# iOS Xcode Swift - How to get hotspot connected devices IP address?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I need to develop an iOS app Using Swift 5 to find my iPhone hotspot connected devices IP info.

Is there any API for it in Swift 5 or any other open source code?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the code below.

For getting the hotspot connected device's IP, use Network.wifi .

```
enum Network: String {
    case wifi = "en0"
    case cellular = "pdp_ip0"
    case ipv4 = "ipv4"
    case ipv6 = "ipv6"
}

func getAddress(for network: Network) -> String? {
    var address: String?

    // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
    var ifaddr: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
    guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return nil }
    guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return nil }

    // For each interface ...
    for ifptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
        let interface = ifptr.pointee

        // Check for IPv4 or IPv6 interface:
        let addrFamily = interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
        if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

            // Check interface name:
            let name = String(cString: interface.ifa_name)
            if name == network.rawValue {

                // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                getnameinfo(interface.ifa_addr, socklen_t(interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len),
                            &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                            nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
                address = String(cString: hostname)
            }
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifaddr)

    return address
}

print("wifi: \(String(describing: getAddress(for: .wifi)))")
```

For more information refer to below links:

[Swift - Get device's WIFI IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748480/swift-get-devices-wifi-ip-address)

[Get IPAddress of iPhone or iPad device Using Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541280/get-ipaddress-of-iphone-or-ipad-device-using-swift-3/44542228)

Comment: Thanks for your info. This gives the app running device IP Address. But I would like to get hotspot connected device IP address. For example, I have enabled personal hotspot in my iPhone and connected my iPad through that hotspot. Now from my iPhone, I would like to get IP address of the iPad using my app.

Comment: @Joe can you tell me how did you get the IP address of iPad using your app? I also need the same thing to do.
Can you help me out?