# Is it possible to get Mobile data IP address in iOS? (not public IP of service provider)

Tags: ios, swift, networking, network-programming, ip

I need to get IP address of iPhone/iPad using cellular network (not WiFi). Does Apple allows this?  If no, is there any alternative way to get IP address?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Here is code to get the IP addresses of *all* running interfaces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626117/how-to-get-ip-address-in-swift – is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Also your cellular network address is probably more complicated than you think. Your interface has an address, but you are then routed through the carrier's network to the Internet through other addresses due to NATs. See your public IP address by going to [this](ipchicken.com)

Comment: So, i can get only my public ip address? No internal IP? @Liam kelly

Comment: You can get both, they are just not the same. Look up Network Address Translation for more information about this.

Comment: Fetching local IP address is officially approved by Apple? @Liam Kelly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my Internal IP using Mobile Data

```
func getIFAddresses() -> [String] {
    var addresses = [String]()

    // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
    guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return [] }
    guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return [] }

    // For each interface ...
    for ptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
        let flags = Int32(ptr.pointee.ifa_flags)
        let addr = ptr.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee

        // Check for running IPv4, IPv6 interfaces. Skip the loopback interface.
        if (flags & (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_LOOPBACK)) == (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING) {
            if addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET) || addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

                // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                if (getnameinfo(ptr.pointee.ifa_addr, socklen_t(addr.sa_len), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                                nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0) {
                    let address = String(cString: hostname)
                    addresses.append(address)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
    return addresses
}
```

Comment: how do you use your function?

Comment: Please explain your need.

Comment: You have the function above, which you stated provides "my Internal IP using Mobile Data". How do you initiate your function and display the `Internal IP using Mobile Data`

Comment: Just simply call this function, it returns your current IP address.

Comment: Doing so provides the following: `["fe80::18f7:7393:83f:4059%pdp_ip1", "2600:380:9ee1:40ff:cc9c:a1e3:aaa5:42ae", "fe80::1842:a161:ecde:914f%en0", "191.162.1.65", "fe80::14b6:c6f:8f0a:ee6%en2", "166.254.23.44", "fe80::7c17:b4ff:feb8:14fa%awdl0", "fe80::e69a:dcff:feca:bd9e%ipsec2", "2600:380:9ee1:40ff:cc9c:a1e3:aaa5:42ae", "fe80::743b:2f15:c49b:264b%utun0", "fe80::111:c3bd:fbbd:bedb%utun1", "fe80::e69a:dcff:feca:bd9e%ipsec4", "2600:380:9ee1:40ff:cc9c:a1e3:aaa5:42ae", "fe80::e69a:dcff:feca:bd9e%ipsec5", "2600:380:9ee1:40ff:cc9c:a1e3:aaa5:42ae"]`. How do I know which one is the IP address?

Comment: can you confirm this is the result you got as well?

Comment: Any solution you found for this.. I am also stuck here. Please let me know @FamicTech

Answer (score 0):

Declare an enum as follows

```
enum NetworkType:String {
    case wifi = "en0"
    case cellular = "pdp_ip0"
}
```

implement the method:

```
class func getNetworkIPAddress(network:String) -> String? {
        var address : String?

        // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
        var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
        guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return nil }
        guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return nil }

        // For each interface ...
        for ifptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
            let interface = ifptr.pointee

            // Check for IPv4 or IPv6 interface:
            let addrFamily = interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
            if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

                // Check interface name:
                let name = String(cString: interface.ifa_name)
                if  name == network {
                    // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                    var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                    getnameinfo(interface.ifa_addr, socklen_t(interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len),
                                &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                                nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
                    address = String(cString: hostname)
                }
            }
        }
        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
        return address
    }
```

method calling:

`let wifiipaddress = getNetworkIPAddress(network:NetworkType.wifi.rawValue)` //it will return current connected wifi address.

`let cellularIPaddress = getNetworkIPAddress(network:NetworkType.cellular.rawValue)` //it will return current connected Cellular IP address.